# Adding and Deleting Row in second tableview based on Condition

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 `UITableViews` in one `ViewController` say table1 and table2. ONclick of an item in one table 1 i am adding that item to table2. One of these items in table1 say `objectAtIndex` 1 shows another `Viewcontrller`. The second `viewcontroller` has a back button and save button. I want to add this item to table 2 only if save button in second view controller was clicked. An Ideas?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if (self.moveItem && self.indexRow != -1) {
    // Your logic to move data from one array to another based on self.indexRow
    // May like below
    // item = [firtsArray objectAtIndex:self.indexRow];
    // [secondArray arrayByAddingObject:item];
    // [firtsArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.indexRow];
    // Reload your both table view

    [selectedCallType addObject:[callType objectAtIndex:self.indexRow]];
    [selectedCallTypeId addObject:[callTypeId objectAtIndex:self.indexRow]];

    self.moveItem = NO;
}

NSLog(@"Call Type Array = %@",selectedCallType);
NSLog(@"Call Type Id Array = %@",selectedCallTypeId);

[table reloadData];
[table2 reloadData];
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: it is only for two tables in one viewcontroller. i have 2 viewcotrollers

Comment: you need to make it more clear

Comment: basically when a click a cell in table 1 i am displaying another viewcontroller which has two buttons (Save & Back). This cell that i clicked should be added to  table2 only if Save was clicked in second view controller.

Comment: when you press tablecell just fetch the pressed cell value like cell.labelText and pass it to next class variable but don add to table 2 when you press save button just add the value to array and show it in table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose you  must create some `variables/property` in `Viewcontrller1`. These properties are used in decision making that you are ready to move your item to `table2`

Create two properties in `Viewcontrller1` like as

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger indexRow;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL moveItem;
```

Create a properties in `Viewcontrller2` like as

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *firstViewController;
```

When you click on any cell of table1 store its `indexPath.row` in `indexRow` as

```
self.indexRow = indexPath.row
```

and move from `Viewcontrller1` to `Viewcontrller2` by storing `Viewcontrller1` reference to created `firstViewController` property as below

```
Viewcontrller2.firstViewController = self;
```

Now in `Viewcontrller2` when you press save button then change the bool value YES/NO (Just opposite when you initialise it) as below

```
// (Let us suppose you initialise it with NO)
self.firstViewController.moveItem = YES
```

Now you in `Viewcontrller1` `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{}` method write your logic to move your item from one array to another and after it reload your both tableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.indexRow = -1;
     self.moveItem = NO;
     // Your other code....
 }

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   if (self.moveItem && self.indexRow != -1) {
       // Your logic to move data from one array to another based on self.indexRow 
       // May like below
       // item = [firtsArray objectAtIndex:self.indexRow];
       // [secondArray arrayByAddingObject:item];
       // [firtsArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.indexRow];
       // Reload your both table view

       // Create New reference of adding object then add it to another array.
       // This will create new reference of adding object, Now add it to second array like below
       // Hope this work. See the array count.
       id *addObject = [callType objectAtIndex:self.indexRow];
       id *addObjectID = [callTypeId objectAtIndex:self.indexRow];
       [selectedCallType addObject:addObject];
       [selectedCallTypeId addObject:addObjectID];

       [table reloadData];
       [table2 reloadData];
       self.moveItem = NO;
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you...

Comment: hey, thanx for explaining. i was out of logics, i will give this a try. Hope is works

Comment: yah, this is the a raw idea that may help you. if you have still any problem after this i will try to help you..

Comment: Hi, i tried your method and i think it worked fine. Still there is a small error. When i come back to firstViewController after clicking save. The second table dosent seem to reload. Data exists in the array.

Comment: is it happening because of this line 'Viewcontrller2.firstViewController = self;' ?

Comment: "Viewcontrller2.firstViewController = self" is only used for getting reference of first viewcontroller to second vcontroller only. May this error occur due to moving data from one array to another. Can u provide the code or update your answer for moving data.

Comment: I have update my answer. check it. is this working? And see array count after moving object from each other.

Comment: I tried it. Still the same problem. The array counts are correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43111/discussion-between-lalit-kumar-and-lexer)

Comment: Hey Lalit , your method worked. The problem was there was a '[table reloaddata]' method in 'cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod' which i overlooked. It worked when i commented that link. Thanx again.